# Does trample damage trigger the ingest ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have an Eldrazi deck that has creatures with the ingest ability:

> Whenever this creature deals combat damage to a player, that player exiles the top card of their library

Would trample damage activate this ability since the trample damage is done to the player?

Answer (score 6):

Per the rules on [Trample](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Trample):

> 702.19a Trample is a static ability that modifies the rules for assigning an attacking creature’s combat damage.

As the wording says, trample lets you assign excess combat damage to the blocking player (or planeswalker or battle). As such, it *is* considered combat damage, and so it will trigger ingest.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought this was correct but I am a new player so I wanted to make sure!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, damage done to a player by a blocked trampling creature is still combat damage.**

> 120.2a Damage may be dealt as a result of combat. Each attacking and blocking creature deals combat damage equal to its power during the combat damage step.

Both the defending player and the creature(s) blocking the trampling creature receive combat damage, no matter how it's distributed due to Trample. All that matters for Ingest is that the defending player receives at least 1 damage from combat.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought this was correct but I am a new player so I wanted to make sure!